# extracting specific text from one file string to use for comparison using Strawberry Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am using Strawberry Perl (64-bit) 5.20.1.1-64bit to perform text replacement. I have several .txt files below the location of my perl script. What I am trying to do is match on a keyword "id:" in any file (i.e. Player7.txt) and extract the ID_PlayerXX from the string to compare within another file. The string will look like this:

```
            id: ID_Player7         // Unique ID
```

A player_ids.txt file contains the actual value I need for my calculation. This file is formatted as follows:

```
#define ID_Player7        236
```

Now I need to match the Player found and extract the actual numerical value associated to that player (236 in this case).

What I am having problems with is removing just the "Player7" portion to use in my substitution.

I think it should look something like this

```
$id_player_file =~ s/(ID_Player\d\d)//;
if ($defined_id =~ m/$id_player_file/) {
   $extracted_value =~ s/$_/\d\d\d$/;
   # $extracted_value calculation here and written to individual player file
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What value you expected / you need in the `$id_player_file` and `$extracted_value` variable in the example above?

Comment: From the example, I need $id_player_file to be "ID_Player7", and $extracted_value should result in "236". Bottom line is the extracted_value is unique to the player and therefore calculations will be different for each. Hope my explanation is not too confusing. Thanks

Comment: Your description is very unclear. It sounds like `$defined_id` is the value from `player_ids.txt` and you want to compare it with the value from the player files like `Player7.txt`? But there is no number in the play file to compare — it just says `id: ID_Player7         // Unique ID`. Please elaborate

Comment: I apologize as I am pretty new to this stuff. I'll try to elaborate a little more; If "id:" is found in "Player##.txt" then pull out of that string the Player ID NAME (i.e. the line -->id: ID_Player7    //Unique ID, should result in $var1 = "ID_Player7"). Next, if $var1 is found in "Player_ids.txt", then find the numerical value assigned to Player7 (ie. the line -->#define ID_Player7        236, should result in $var2=236). Hope this helps clear up my question, and thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably this is what you want to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $id_player_file = "            id: ID_Player7         // Unique ID" ;
my $defined_id     = "#define ID_Player7        236"                   ;   

$id_player_file =~ s/.*\bid: (\w+\d+).*/\1/;
printf "id_player_file=[%s]\n", $id_player_file; # print "ID_Player7"

my $extracted_value = undef;

# Check whether ['ID_Player7'+whitespaces+number] exist $defined_id
if ( $defined_id =~ m/$id_player_file\s+(\d+)/ ) { 
    # If yes, retrieve the number after whitespaces (inside parentheses above)
    $extracted_value = $1; 
}

printf "extracted_value=[%s]\n", $extracted_value;
```

Note: `\d+` means one or more digits, `\s+` means one or more whitespaces

Output:

```
id_player_file=[ID_Player7]
extracted_value=[236]
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I'm looking for. The only thing is that in the string "            id: ID_Player7         // Unique ID", Player7, can be any Name## combo, (i.e. ID_Blue25, Green01, Flyer36, etc.). So this may need a little massage to the substitution

Comment: Updated my answer to cover 'any id:'.

Comment: If you need to affect only string containing `id: ID_`, that is excluding `id: FOO` etc, just replace `(\w+\d+)` with `(ID_\w+\d+)` .

Comment: This worked! I am still trying to understand the regex, but just need practice. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown anywhere near enough of your program to get an idea of the context, but this should help. It reads only one player file as you don't say what you want to do with them all, but the general idea should work. It's more likely that you should build a hash structure out of the contents of `player_ids.txt`, but it's impossible to advise you with just this information

If you need any more help then please show your program and data files

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $player_fh, '<', 'Player7.txt';
open my $ids_fh, '<', 'player_ids.txt';

while ( <$player_fh> ) {

  next unless /^\s*id:\s*(\w+)/;

  my $id_player_file = $1;

  while ( <$ids_fh> ) {
    next unless /^\s*#define\s+$id_player_file\s+(\d+)/;

    my $extracted_value = $1;
    ...
    last;
  }

  last;
}
```